# Is it possible to view Github's Dependency Graph for a specific branch rather than the entire repository?

Tags: git, security, github, version-control, dependencies

As the title states, I was wondering if it was possible to view a Dependency Graph in a Github repository for a specific Branch or Tag in that repository, rather than for the entire repository itself, based off of the Master branch.

I address a lot of CVEs as part of my routine maintenance of some components that I own at my job, so I use the Dependency Graph to see what CVEs/vulnerabilities are active in my Direct and Transitive Dependencies, and apply updates accordingly, and would love the ability to commit my changes to my branch and check a Dependency Graph to ensure that I've made all the necessary dependency updates without having to open a PR and merge to Master.

Thank you!

Comment: As of Jan 2023, Github only supports default branch for dependency graphs and dependabot alerts.